# Can dogs *actually* kiss? Not lick, but kiss

Tags: dogs, behavior, physiology

Do dogs (or only specific breeds) have the physiology - both muscular and neural - to be able to to kiss? I don't mean contact of the lips or "kissing" that is *actually* licking - I meas creating negative air pressure in the mouth that pulls the lips shut against each under pressure other and releasing it (usually after contact with some surface e.g lips or skin, and usually also while pushing them against that surface).

Answer (score 2):

No. Same reason they can't drink by sucking and have to inefficiently lap water up with their tongues: the lips can't get an adequate seal. Muzzles mostly just don't work that way.